# Android get phone number from contact list

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have these codes which basically use a ListView to display the names in the contact list and I want to get their phone number when click each single name:

```
final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

final Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, c, new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, new int[]{R.id.TVRow}, 0);
myPhoneList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

myPhoneList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

In the `onItemClick` Method the

```
    GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
```

returns -1 and therefore I cannot get the phone number with this method.

I've also tried to print out all the columns of the cursor `c` and it returns 34 columns but the only column which seems to be related to the phone number is `HasPhoneNumber`.

So where's the problem and how can I fix it? Thanks!

---

The updated version, where the `String` array passed to construct `myCursorAdapter` is changed:

```
final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    final Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, c, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}, new int[]{R.id.TVRow}, 0);
    myPhoneList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    myPhoneList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            c.moveToPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I suppose the updated code will show the phone numbers in the ListView but I got an error says "column 'data1' does not exist".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContactsContract` Android API stores data about contacts like phone number in the `Data` table, not the `Contacts` table.

Read this carefully: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html.

**Update** - here's a fixed version of your code (untested):

```
final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String[] projection = new String[] {Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};
final Cursor c = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, c, new String[] {Phone.NUMBER}, new int[]{R.id.TVRow}, 0);
myPhoneList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

myPhoneList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all add this line in AndroidManifest.xml to take permission from user.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

implement the button of contact

```
        phoneContactsButtton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            // The below two line is needed to open the contact list of  mobile
                Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent,1);

            }
        });
```

you have to override the onActivityResult() which will be written to the outside of onCreate() mehtod
similar to this

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode){
        case 1 :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();

                Cursor cur =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (cur.getCount() > 0) {// thats mean some resutl has been found
                    if(cur.moveToNext()) {
                        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        Log.e("Names", name);

                        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                        {

                            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
                            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                Log.e("Number", phoneNumber);
                            }
                            phones.close();
                        }

                    }
                }
                cur.close();
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code for getting contact list in Recyclerview;

```
  List<ContactVO> contactVOList = new ArrayList();

  String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI};
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    List<ContactVO> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    String lastPhoneName = " ";
    if (phones.getCount() > 0) {
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String contactId = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String photoUri = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
            if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(lastPhoneName)) {
                lastPhoneName = name;
                ContactVO user = new ContactVO();
                user.setContactName(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                user.setContactNumber(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                userList.add(user);
                Log.d("getContactsList", name + "---" + phoneNumber + " -- " + contactId + " -- " + photoUri);
            }
        }
    }
    phones.close();

    AllContactsAdapter contactAdapter = new AllContactsAdapter(userList, getApplicationContext());
    rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(PhoneDirectoryActivity.this));
    rvContacts.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

Below `ContactVO` class file;

```
public class ContactVO
{
private String ContactImage;
private String ContactName;
private String ContactNumber;

public String getContactImage() {
    return ContactImage;
}

public void setContactImage(String contactImage) {
    this.ContactImage = ContactImage;
}

public String getContactName() {
    return ContactName;
}

public void setContactName(String contactName) {
    ContactName = contactName;
}

public String getContactNumber() {
    return ContactNumber;
}

public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
    ContactNumber = contactNumber;
}
}
```

and below is `AllContactsAdapter` file

```
    public class AllContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllContactsAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

    private List<ContactVO> contactVOList;
    private Context mContext;
    private SparseBooleanArray itemStateArray = new SparseBooleanArray();

    public AllContactsAdapter(List<ContactVO> contactVOList, Context mContext) {
        this.contactVOList = contactVOList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.single_contact_view, null);
        ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder(view);
        return contactViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ContactVO contactVO = contactVOList.get(position);
        holder.tvContactName.setText(contactVO.getContactName());
        holder.tvPhoneNumber.setText(contactVO.getContactNumber());

        holder.bind(position);

        holder.cbContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int adapterPosition = position;
                if (!itemStateArray.get(adapterPosition, false)) {
                    holder.cbContact.setChecked(true);
                    contactsList.add(holder.tvPhoneNumber.getText().toString());
                    itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, true);
                } else {
                    holder.cbContact.setChecked(false);
                    itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, false);
                    contactsList.remove(holder.tvPhoneNumber.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactVOList.size();
    }

    public class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView ivContactImage;
        TextView tvContactName;
        TextView tvPhoneNumber;
        CheckBox cbContact;

        public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ivContactImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivContactImage);
            tvContactName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
            tvPhoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNumber);
            cbContact = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbContact);
        }
        void bind(int arg1) {
            // use the sparse boolean array to check
            if (!itemStateArray.get(arg1, false)) {
                cbContact.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                cbContact.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it returns -1 because you don't request the column `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` from DB:

```
new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}
```

`ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` is the only field you request.

To be able to get the phone number, you firstly need to include it into list of columns you want to get from DB:

new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}`

Now you have to override adapter's `getView` so it sets the name into the textView of the list row. After that your `onItemClick` will work as expected

Comment: I tried with only ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER in the String[] and get the error: column 'data1' does not exist. I think since I have already included all the fields in the query, the cursor should contain the field about phone number, and the adapter should not be the cause?

Comment: @T.Yu, I did not understand what you changed and what is a problem now

Comment: I changed new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME} to new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER} and I suppose it will show the phone numbers in the ListView but I got an error says "column 'data1' does not exist".

Comment: @T.Yu, ok, `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` might be a wrong column name. Let me check it

Comment: It should be. Almost all the relative posts on the Internet I've visited so far use this column.

Answer (score 0):

This Answer just a small update from above answers. It may help to someone.

**StarActivityForResult** is deprecated. So we can use below model in Kotlin.

In Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

***Please implement run-time permission also. I haven't done in my code.***

**Below lines used to handle the result:**

```
    private val openContacts = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickContact()) {

    val contactData: Uri = it
    val phone: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(contactData!!, null, null, null, null)
    if (phone!!.moveToFirst()) {
        val contactName: String = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))

        // To get number - runtime permission is mandatory.
        val id: String = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
        if (phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)).toInt() > 0) {
            val phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null)
            while (phones!!.moveToNext()) {
                val phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                Log.d("## Number", phoneNumber)
            }
            phones!!.close()
        }

        Log.d("## Contact Name", contactName)
    }

}
```

**To open the contacts:**

```
button.setOnClickListener {
        openContacts.launch(null)
    }
```