# How to get phone number from android phone

Tags: android, telephonymanager

How to get the phone number from an android phone. I have used this code but it doesn't get the current number. It get the number that came with the phone, so if I change the SIM it gets the previous number.

```
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String number = manager.getLine1Number();
```

This code gets a number but not the the current one. How would I get the current number.

Comment: do you want the phone number stored in contacts??

Comment: @sumit Maybet it would be OK to get it from contacts. But not everyone would set their number in contacts

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
```

and use:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: I've tried that. That doesn't get the phone number. That just gets a random string of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Sim serial Number and sim number is unique. You can try this for get sim serial number and get sim number and Don't forget to add permission in manifest file.

```
 TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

 String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
 String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
```

And add below permission into your Androidmanifest.xml file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

**Note : it is only possible in single sim phone , if you try with dual sim phone then you not getting your phone number.**

Comment: I might also check to see if they have set it in the 'Me' contact. How to I access the Me contact and get the number

Comment: @DeclanMarks This link may be helpful to you.

https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40866451/5742249