# How to fetch all users of my app from contact list like WhatApp does in Firebase chat app

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a chatting app like WhatsApp using firebase. Everything is fine, but I am stuck at fetching all users who using my app from contacts like WhatsApp does... How can I fetch all users from my contact list to recyclerView

Comment: You can map contacts in phone and users who are registered(data which is on server)

Comment: Check Out My Answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64399981/13124119)
or from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/64399981/13124119

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of contacts using `READ_CONTACTS` permission.

[Retrieving a List of Contacts](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)

```
final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String[] projection = new String[] {Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};
final Cursor c = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, c, new String[] {Phone.NUMBER}, new int[]{R.id.TVRow}, 0);
myPhoneList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

myPhoneList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

[Link to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40861846/8405762)

Then you will need to guarantee your user set the correct phone number when register to you App. To do that i suggest a validation by SMS

[Here it is a post explaining a registration with SMS validation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview)

Just then you will know a user how has a phone number in his contact list is friend with another user in your database.

Comment: i have done so but how to write next code to check that the who  is registered or not..

Comment: To answer this I would have to write a chapter of a book. Check this post: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/. This post describe how to save and read a user register. Dont forget to include a `phone` member to `User` class